# Why doesn't Stack Overflow Careers have comments and votes?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I have seen some of the advertisements they have put which aren't happening in reality. Some of the vacancies are trying to exaggerate and are trying to attract people. But internal structures and culture inside those companies are totally miserable.

I think if anyone can see some comments and people can recommend some of which are really good companies, that would be useful to many of us. It will definitely increase the real value of Stack Overflow Careers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think the voting system would be an answer to this. Bigger companies could just pressure their employees into voting for them and for posting favorable comments.

The voting and commenting system are based on the principle of peer review; those voting and commenting can be expected to know the subject matter, that is available to all.
The internal structure and atmosphere of a company is not as publicly visible as the mechanics of a programming language, and is inherently more subjective. Different people have different preferences.

If you believe a company is deliberately misrepresenting itself, then you could take this up with the SO Careers staff. "Naming and shaming" is unlikely to be helpful, and may be detrimental to your own career.